# Eigenvalue by Gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&4&0\\-2&4&-1\\2&-5&0 \end{bmatrix}$

I want to find out the eigenvalue of matrix my Gaussian elimination. My idea was to make the matrix triangular and by that being able to write an expression for the determinant that equals 0. Like this:  $(aλ+a_1)(bλ+b_1)(cλ+c_1)$

My try:

$ \det \begin{vmatrix} λ+1&-4&0\\2&λ-4&1\\-2&5&λ \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} λ+1&0&0\\2&λ-4+\frac{8}{(λ+1)}&1\\-2&5-\frac{8}{(λ+1)}&λ \end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix} λ+1&0&0\\2&λ-4+\frac{8}{(λ+1)}&0\\-2&5-\frac{8}{(λ+1)}&\frac{5-\frac{8}{(λ+1)}}{-4+\frac{8}{(λ+1)}} \end{vmatrix}$,

which would give the equation: $ (λ+1)(λ-4+\frac{8}{(λ+1)})(\frac{5-\frac{8}{(λ+1)}}{-4+\frac{8}{(λ+1)}})=0 $

Now solving each of the parentheses for λ, should give me the right Eigenvalues  if I understand the concept of eigenvalues. Am I doing anything wrong or do i simply not understand eigenvalues yet?

Comment: I got $$[1,3,-1]$$

Comment: I don't understand your transformations to calculate the determinant.

Comment: If I have a triangular matrix the product of the diagonal should be the determinant right?

Comment: Of course, but I still don't see your transformations.

Comment: So i'm eliminating column 2 first: $W(λ+1)=4 <=> W = \frac{4}{λ+1}$ Where W is what i multiply the other values of column 1 with. Then i simply add that product to column 2. Some procedure for column 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to obtain the characteristic polynomial:
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+1&-4&0\\ 2&\lambda- 4&\phantom{-}\\-2&5&\lambda
\end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+1&-4&0\\ 0&\lambda+1&\lambda+1\\-2&5&\lambda
\end{vmatrix} =
(\lambda+1)\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+1&-4&0\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\-2&5&\lambda
\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
={}
(\lambda+1)&\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+1&-4&4\\ 0 & 1 &  0\\-2&5&\lambda -5
\end{vmatrix} = (\lambda+1)\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda+1&4 \\-2&\lambda -5
\end{vmatrix}=(\lambda+1)\bigl((\lambda+1)(\lambda-5)+8\bigr)\\[1ex]
=(\lambda+1)&(\lambda^2-4\lambda+3)=(\lambda+1)(\lambda-1)(\lambda-3).
\end{align}